# error in depolying contract >> Error: could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.7.2)

Tags: deployment, smartcontracts, hardhat

im trying the depoy my contract using npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network goerli and i keep geeting the above error
//this is the error

```
omota@DESKTOP-3T9OR5N MINGW32 ~/web3-projects/tinder-blockchain/smart-contract (main)
$ npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network goerli
Compiled 1 Solidity file successfully
error in depolying contract >> Error: could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.7.2)
    at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\omota\web3-projects\tinder-blockchain\smart-contract\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
    at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\omota\web3-projects\tinder-blockchain\smart-contract\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
    at EthersProviderWrapper.<anonymous> (C:\Users\omota\web3-projects\tinder-blockchain\smart-contract\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:483:23)
    at step (C:\Users\omota\web3-projects\tinder-blockchain\smart-contract\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:48:23)
    at Object.throw (C:\Users\omota\web3-projects\tinder-blockchain\smart-contract\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:29:53)
    at rejected (C:\Users\omota\web3-projects\tinder-blockchain\smart-contract\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:21:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  reason: 'could not detect network',
  code: 'NETWORK_ERROR',
  event: 'noNetwork'
}
```

//here is my depoy.js file

```
const { ethers } = require('hardhat')

const main = async () => {
  const tinderFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('TinderERC721')
  const tinderContract = await tinderFactory.deploy()

  console.log('TINDER CONTRACT ADDRESS:', tinderContract.address)
};

main()
.then(() => process.exit(0))
.catch(error => {
console.log('error in depolying contract >>', error);
process.exit(1);
})
```

//here is my hardhat-config.js

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require('dotenv').config({path: '.env'})

const ALCHEMY_API_URL = process.env.ALCHEMY_API_URL
const GOERLI_PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.GOERLI_PRIVATE_KEY

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: 'goerli',
  networks: {
    goerli: {
      url: ALCHEMY_API_URL,
      accounts: [`0x${GOERLI_PRIVATE_KEY}`],
    },
  },
  solidity: '0.8.17',
}
```

any help will be appreciated

i have done anything i can but still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error. Since you are using .env to store the private keys, if the value is being stored as:
"https://eth-goerli.alchemyapi.io/v2/**${ALCHEMY_API_KEY}**" within the .env file itself, change it to the full link instead:
"https://eth-goerli.alchemyapi.io/v2/**xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx**"

I was also getting a "private key too long" error as well because of using semi-colons to separate statements within the .env file... Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some problems with the ALCHEMY_API_URL. It should be in the form:

```
https://eth-goerli.alchemyapi.io/v2/${ALCHEMY_API_KEY}
```

Or for sure, you can use public RPC nodes:

```
https://goerli.infura.io/v3/         //default on metamask
https://rpc.ankr.com/eth_goerli      //I tried and it worked
https://eth-goerli.public.blastapi.io
https://rpc.goerli.mudit.blog
```